# Action Script 3 delay after i click in button link

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash, button, delay

I have got a problem. I connect my flash button with jQuery and fadeIn /fade out connection working very nice.

But i have problem when i add this code:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("contact.html"), "_self");
```

for this:

```
function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("myfadeout");
}
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("contact.html"), "_self");
```

And fade out if i click doesn't work, because navigateToURL don't accept .delay mettod from jQuery. This metod need other .delay effect

I need only 3 sec pause if i click button and after 3 sec when jQuery fade out page and navigateToURL start link to contact.html

Please help me. I'm graphic designer and i don't very good in action script. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

function ContactBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("myfadeout");
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("contact.html"), "_self"); 
    }, 3000);
}

function AboutBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("myfadeout");
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("about.html"), "_self"); 
    }, 3000);
}   

function AnotherBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("myfadeout");
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("another.html"), "_self"); 
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: This is very nice Idea but my page sometimes only fade out and stop loading contact.html and other links. Of course i change good my function name from AboutBtnClick to onClick1, onClick2 etc...

Have you got idea how to fix this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Ok you're a genius too. :)

I find bug in fade out "body"

You know... If jQuery have got fade Out (3000) and flash have got   setTimeout (3000) - then there is no flash and flash can't link to contact.html for example.

But i change setTimeout from (3000) to (2990) and it's worked and look sexy. ;)

Thank you so much! You're cool! :)

Comment: Now I'm happy because you find the fix for your problem, and thank you for accepting my answer :)

Comment: @ArletaKoźmińska I'm just wondering , isn't it easier for you to pass the desired url to your jQuery via ExternalInterface and handle the navigation there after fading out? that will be easier for you to debug and will not relay on two timing functions (Flash + jQuery), like this : //
ExternalInterface.call("myfadeout", "contact.html");

Comment: @Amer, I think that's way too advanced for her... :)

Comment: @Pier I'm just trying to help her to fight in one place instead of two :)

Comment: @ArletaKoźmińska see my answer to your other question, it may be more helpful in your case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506501/link-button-in-action-script3-fade-out-in-jquerry-integration/#19531421

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`.

```
function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("myfadeout");
    setTimeout(navigate, 3000);
}

function navigate(){
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("contact.html"), "_self"); 
}
```

You will have to import to be able to use it

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
```

Comment: Pier - you're a genius. :) It's working in one button.

But i have got only one question

If i have got 3 button and 3  other links - how i can use more function navigate(){?

If i copy in other button i have got this problem 1021: Duplicate function definition.

Could you help me please? In the future I'll can help you with graphic design. :)

Comment: Thanks, you could use a different name for each function such as `navigateToContact`, `navigateToHome`, etc. If you find the answer useful please accept it clicking in the checkmark icon ;)